# Difference between cmake .. and cmake ../

Tags: cmake

Is there a difference between the two commands `cmake ..` and `cmake ../`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer :**

No.

**Explanations :**

The second argument of `cmake` is the path to the `CMakeLists.txt` and `..` and `../` are both equal to `..`